# Iterate over array of object using map till the second last object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an array of objects where all objects have the same keys except the last object. Think like array have values and to denote all these values as a whole I have a key I am pushing the key at last along with the values in the array.

**homeTask** is a list of object which is the values and **homeTaskKey** is the key to represent the homeTask

```
        res.data.resultSet.homeTask.forEach(element => {
                      var singleEvent={
                        task:'',
                        taskDuration:'',
                        status:'',
                      };

                      singleEvent.task=element.task;
                      singleEvent.taskDuration=element.taskDuration;
                      singleEvent.status=element.status;

                      newEvents.push(singleEvent);


                    });
                    newEvents.push(res.data.resultSet.homeTaskKey);


                   addEvent(newEvents);
              }
```

`addEvent` is props method of parent component where I am setting the array to state variable name as `events` which is array type.

When I iterate over `events` using `map` I want to skip the last object since it does not have keys like task, taskDuration and status. Therefore it won't give any problem when I fetch those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
events.slice(0, events.length-1).map(<function>);
```

this will ignore the last element and all n-1 entries will be fed to map

**UPDATE**:

the array name is events not event therefore it should be events.length

Comment: `events.slice(0, event.length-1).map((event) =>{});` where each event Failed to compile
Events.js
  Line 382:  Unexpected use of 'event'  no-restricted-globals
  Line 393:  Unexpected use of 'event'  no-restricted-globals

Comment: Can u provide a sample input and output so that I can test as well

Comment: lets say I have events
`[{task: "house cleaning", taskDuration:60, status:"n/a"}, {task: "waste dumping", taskDuration:30, status:"n/a"}, {task: "dishwashing", taskDuration:80, status:"n/a"}, {address: "90/1, park street road london", landmark:"neville's studio"}]`

Now last object is the key

Comment: var events = [{task: "house cleaning", taskDuration:60, status:"n/a"}, {task: "waste dumping", taskDuration:30, status:"n/a"}, {task: "dishwashing", taskDuration:80, status:"n/a"}, {address: "90/1, park street road london", landmark:"neville's studio"}]; 
console.log(events.slice(0, events.length-1).map((event) =>event.task));

Comment: also in events.slice(0, event.length-1).map((event) =>{});  event.length is wrong, it should be events.length just FYI

Comment: Though I have already implemented someone's else logic just correct your answer `events.length`

Answer (score 1):

You could still use `map`, but simply pop the last element off once the map completes. For example:

```
const newEvents = homeTask.map(({ task, taskDuration, status }) => ({
  task, taskDuration, status
}))
newEvents.pop()
addEvent(newEvents)
```

Or just replace the last item with your taskkey, as you know the last item will be junk:

```
newEvents[newEvents.length - 1] = res.data.resultSet.homeTaskKey
```

Or just `slice` the array prior to mapping, and then push the taskKey at the end like you were doing. slice is safe to perform on your prop, as it shallow copies.

---

Or most importantly, ask yourself why you have this entirely weird data structure that has the key appended on the end. Perhaps rethink your data and not create this problem for yourself in the first place.

Comment: when I pass this props from child-parent-anotherChild.....I am having the table where each row represent the object and it has a button when I click on the button it should pass this key and that row(means single object).....I don't want to add it to another variable though I can do that easily

Comment: So couldn't you pass `{ key: 'something', items: [] }`? Rather than merge it all into a single array?

Comment: yes it did resolve though I have to change lot of things since now it's not array rather than object inside this object I have array.....changing data structure involves huge amount of work wherever I am using this same data...though it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
res.data.resultSet.homeTask.forEach((element,index) => {})
```

second param to function is index you, can use this to identify the second last element by comparing it with total length of array.

Comment: I posted (and already deleted) the same answer, but when using `map()` as per the question, this gives issues because the result array will have a last `undefined` element.

Comment: Op mentioned `forEach` in code. I think he is confused.

Answer (score 0):

hmm you can try with this

```
res.data.resultSet.homeTask.forEach(element => {
    if(!element.task)
        return false;
    ...bla bla bla
}
```

Comment: `console.log("this event:"+events.slice(0, event.length-1).sort((a, b) =>
       a.expectedEnd.split(':').reverse().join().localeCompare(b.expectedEnd.split(':').reverse().join())));`  how will you avoid in this case

Answer (score 0):

The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element.

So it creates an array of same length from source array.

What you need is filter()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Something like this;

```
const tasks = res.data.resultSet.homeTask.filter((element) => {
  const { task, taskDuration, status } = element;
  return task && taskDuration && status; 
});
```

Comment: let me put this straight resultSet has homeTask which is a list of object I just put these object into an array and then resultSet has homeTaskKey now this is associated with homeTask(the whole list) if I iterate over this array each row in a table has a button and on clicking the button it should send that single object means row + the key for whole array means homeTaskKey........but in a table I don't want to have a row for homeTaskKey if I don't slice it then it will give my key too